# Trigger Alexa notifications from Alexa skill lambda?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-notification

Does it comply with Amazon guidelines if I trigger Alexa notifications from Alexa skill lambda itself without an external lambda? ie directly calling `api.amazonalexa.com/v2/notifications` without any external triggers?

**Original Alexa notification flow**

---

[image]

**My implementation**

---

[image]
​
​
​
​
​
​

Comment: Alexa notifications is in developer preview, only few developers has access to it? Are you one of them?

Comment: @CicilThomas Yes.

Comment: That's not gonna work, you removed the consent token out of the equation which is precisely why the extra steps are there. Do you want to send notifications without consent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This architecture is approved by Alexa team. The skill is live now. Hence we can conclude that it conforms to Amazon guidelines.